# Update query interrupted in workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The first query returns an expected set of records but when I run the update query and refresh, It immediately says 'query interrupted' but there are no messages.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = 0;
UPDATE table SET value = 99 WHERE value = 0;
```

I can manually update the tables, so I don't think there is a permissions issue.
What could be causing a query interruption in this case?

Version: 6.3.7

Comment: workbench is a joke, grab something better, shell will provide with much better information to rely on.

Comment: @deepcell yea i abandoned workbench shortly after, ha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a default thousand-row limit in MySQL-Workbench. The SELECT query will return results but UPDATE will fail if the number of records to be updated exceeds one thousand. One option is to limit the number of records to be updated in the query itself or you can adjust the settings as stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try limit to 100 rows, it worked for me.
The options above the query window, beside the query button there is a option to limit the rows obtained. This might help you